# Картинки в spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Нужно чтобы в spinner были смайлики, а не цифры. Есть 5 картинок, нужно чтобы отображались картинки, а не текст, а уже на программном уровне (в бд) будyт цифры (1-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создайте свой адаптер для спинера.
2. В его методе `getview()` найдите по id `ImageView` созданной вами же разметки для элемента спиннера.
3. Установите туда картинку.

Примеры кода с [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22216375/3212712)